# Using Rating/Like feature on a Summary View web part for announcements

Tags: list-view, rating

I have created an announcement list on my SP13 site with ratings turned on using the like button.  I have put a web part to my list on the homepage of a team site. When I use the default "all list" item view in the web part, the like button is there. When I change it to the "Summary View" which is a nicer way to read the annoucments, the like button is gone.  I tried changing the view for the summary view and add the like button column but it just gives me a 0 or a 1 instead of the like button. Is there a way to get the like button to work with the summary view?  It seems like it should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

The summary view is a carry over from 2010. I believe the AllItems.aspx view uses new client-side rendering techniques to display the ratings/like field. You'd want to take a look at 'SP.UI.Reputation.js' file to see how it's implemented.

Option 1: You can mimic the summary view using the JSLink and implement your ratings/like system. Easy but time consuming I would say.

Option 2: Customize XSLT and then implement ratings. See example here: https://erikyadams.wordpress.com/2014/05/07/press-the-like-button-my-friend/

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the article! I have been unable to find any